# SharePoint Online: 2010, 2013

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-online

Please help with the question below.

I would like to have a clear picture in my head in regard:

- Does any newly created SPO/Office 365 account will utilize SPO 2013, and not 2010? Can I force using 2010?
- Is there any time limit for existing SPO 2010 instances to exist? Will they unavoidably converted to 2013?

Googling around this did not give me a clear answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New Office 365 subscriptions will always use the latest rolled out version. You can't create 2010 Site collections in an Office 365 subscription that is running version 2013. It may look like you can do it using [PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161370.aspx) But if you try, you will only get an error message that says "Compatibility level 14 is not supported".

Existing SPO 2010 subscriptions will be unavoidably upgraded. You are allowed to [postpone](http://community.office365.com/en-us/wikis/upgrade/postpone.aspx) the upgrade if the date scheduled for your update is inconvenient for you, but you can only do that once.